# Looping through records for different 'consumers' to return number of days between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I have been looking through the questions around looping through records but have been unable to find anything that could solve my problem

So I have a table of consumer entries into a campaign. The profile_id is specific to a consumer, here we have two consumers.  We see the campaign they entered and the date of entry, with a count telling us which entry it is (chronologically)

```
profile_id    campaign   create_date    entry      
74704338      2320        28-07-2015      1
74704338      2388        28-01-2016      2
74704338      2464        29-04-2016      3
74704338      2476        03-05-2016      4
74704338      2505        25-05-2016      5
81990916      2320        05-11-2015      1
81990916      2388        22-01-2016      2
81990916      2464        28-04-2016      3
81990916      2467        28-04-2016      4
81990916      2434        02-05-2016      5
```

What I want to do is run through each record for each profile (consumer) and get the max. no of days between the n and the n+1 entry, and the campaign associated with it.

So for profile_id 74704338 we should get the following as the days between 1 and 2 is the largest in the sequence, and campaign 2388 was the campaign they entered after this time elapsed

```
profile_id    campaign   num_days
74704338      2388       184
```

Similarly for 81990916 we should get

```
profile_id    campaign   num_days
81990916      2464       97
```

I presume I will be using a declare statement to do this, but have no idea where to start. Would appreciate your help

Many thanks

Comment: In any question where you ask about "the largest", "the most", "the longest" etc. you should state what should happen (what the desired result is) when there are ties. What if there were two campaigns tied for the largest number of days between created_dates?

Comment: thanks but there wont be any ties as the date field is actually datetime so that's not a problem, i just shortened it here for handiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytic functions were created just for this kind of exercises. First we compute the differences (using the `lag()` function), then the maximum difference within each "partition" by `profile_id`, and then in the last (outermost) query we select the rows where the difference equals the maximum.

I wrote this using syntax from Oracle 11.2 and above; for earlier versions, it can be rewritten by creating the column aliases inside the subquery definitions (instead of in their declarations).

```
with
     test_data ( profile_id, campaign, create_date ) as (      
       select 74704338, 2320, to_date('28-07-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 74704338, 2388, to_date('28-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 74704338, 2464, to_date('29-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 74704338, 2476, to_date('03-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 74704338, 2505, to_date('25-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 81990916, 2320, to_date('05-11-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 81990916, 2388, to_date('22-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 81990916, 2464, to_date('28-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 81990916, 2467, to_date('28-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 81990916, 2434, to_date('02-05-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual
     ),
     diffs ( profile_id, campaign, create_date, diff ) as (
       select profile_id, campaign, create_date,
              create_date - lag(create_date) over (partition by profile_id 
                                                   order by create_date)
       from   test_data
     ),
     with_max ( profile_id, campaign, create_date, diff, max_diff ) as (
       select profile_id, campaign, create_date, diff,
              max(diff) over (partition by profile_id)
       from   diffs
     )
select profile_id, campaign, create_date, diff
from   with_max
where  diff = max_diff
;

PROFILE_ID  CAMPAIGN CREATE_DATE  DIFF
---------- --------- ----------- -----
  74704338      2388 28-01-2016    184
  81990916      2464 28-04-2016     97

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: mathguy, that is brilliant! thanks a million - make it look so simple

Answer (score 0):

This is the another way of getting the records. Cost is 5. mathguy answer cost is 22.

```
select *
  from (select *
          from (select profile_id,
                       campaign_id,create_date,
                       (create_date - lag(create_date, 1, create_date)
                        OVER(PARTITION BY profile_id ORDER BY ENTRY
                             NULLS LAST)) nod
                  from campaign)
         order by nod desc)
 where rownum <= 2
```

Comment: actually Gopi, what I'm looking for is the largest number of days between one entry and the next. this returns the date and multiple entries for each profile, when it should return one

Comment: I have modified the existing query. Plz check and let me know.